# Password Complexity Issue with B2B Invitation Redemption page

Tags: azure-active-directory

I’m looking for some guidance with respect to an issue with AAD B2B redemption page. 
The below scenario sums up the problem, if you need more details please ask.

1. The application Admin adds a new user to the Application say xyz@abc.com (external users, not hybrid or from different tenant)
2. The user gets an invitation.
3. The user clicks the invitation and sets a password (sample screen shown below).
   [image]
4. The user receives an invitation code to the email account mentioned above
5. The user enters the code and clicks next and receives an error as shown below.

[image]

When we traced it back with the help from the Azure support team we got to know that the password was not strong (for ex: contains part of user id), but the error information on the page or the password instructions (8-character minimum) does not clearly mention that. Below are the criteria we passed to the customer which we gathered as part of our conversations with the support team, but we are looking at onboarding ~500 users during the product launch and this is at high risk as we will not be able to pass this to all users or enforce

A strong password must be used. A strong password includes:
•   A minimum of 8 characters and a maximum of 16 characters.
•   Requires three out of four of the following:
o   Lowercase characters. (a – z)
o   Uppercase characters. (A – Z)
o   Numbers (0-9).
o   Symbols (see the previous password restrictions).
•   Do not use a part of your user id in the password.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft enforces a strong password considering security for the cloud user. The password policy is the same as you said. For more details, you could read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#password-policies-that-only-apply-to-cloud-user-accounts).

> but the error information on the page or the password instructions
>   (8-character minimum) does not clearly mention that

For this issue, you could get the support in the [Azure AD feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).